# how to parse and get url from a common string

Tags: go

I want to parse and get url from a string such as `hello google.comxxx`，the output should be `google.com`, is there any easy way to do that?

Comment: What do you mean by ".comxxx".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a package named [xurls](https://github.com/mvdan/xurls) which you can use.

```golang
import "mvdan.cc/xurls/v2"

func main() {
    rxRelaxed := xurls.Relaxed()
    rxRelaxed.FindString("Do gophers live in golang.org?")  // "golang.org"
    rxRelaxed.FindString("This string does not have a URL") // ""

    rxStrict := xurls.Strict()
    rxStrict.FindAllString("must have scheme: http://example.com/.", -1) // []string{"http://example.com/"}
    rxStrict.FindAllString("no scheme, no match: example.com", -1)       // []string{}
}
```